# How can I use fetch API to populate a DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch

I am trying to fetch the html of a page (once I can get this working I will be fetching a specific Div in the requested page) then print this page in to my `id="data"` div. I can see the information coming through in the promise but I am unable to access that information.

```js
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "https://www.booking.com"; // site that doesn’t send Access-Control-*
fetch(proxyurl + url) // https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com
  .then(response => response)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.text());
    return document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data.text();
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?" + err));
```

```html
<div id='data'></div>
```

Comment: `.then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data;
      })`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `.text()` method you invoke on response body returns a promise. So the proper way to access it would be through the promise chain.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text):

> The text() method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with a USVString object (text).

Here's how your updated snippet should look like:

```js
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "https://www.booking.com"; // site that doesn’t send Access-Control-*
fetch(proxyurl + url) // https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com
  .then(response => response.text())  
.then(html => {
  // console.log(html);
  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = html;
})
.catch((err) => console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?" + err));
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
       <div id='data'>
      </div>
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan ah, didn't even notice the `return` there! *Updated*

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` or `json()` can be called only once. In your code, you're calling it twice. So the console.log gives you the data and the next time when you call `data.text()`, the result is empty.

You could do it as below

```js
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "https://www.booking.com"; // site that doesn’t send Access-Control-*
fetch(proxyurl + url) // https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com
  .then(response => response)
  .then(data => {
    const resData = data.text();
    console.log(resData);
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = resData;
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?" + err));
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: Still shows a promise object. And why return the result of an innerHTML assignement? `return document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = resData;`

Comment: return is not required.

Comment: The main issue is that you cant use the `text()` or `json()` only once. What i'm doing is assigning to a variable and then accessing the variable. as simple as that.