# How to execute an external html/javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

The scenario for my frontend javascript application is as following:

1. GET via URL an html/javascript file
2. execute it

Current I am trying the following frontend approach:

```
const myElement = document.createElement('myElement');
myElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://.../file.html');
document.body.appendChild(myElement);
```

And file.html looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="Javascript">
      function doSomething() { }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="doSomething()"></body>
</html>
```

But nothing is happening.

Am I wrong to expect that on document.body.appendChild() , the file will be downloaded and executed as if the URL was opened from the browser?

Comment: You are creating a tag <myElement> with a src attribute to an file.html. If you create a document.createElement('script'); then add the attribute src to a file.js then it will run.

Comment: To add html to a page you need to download the html with say a fetch, then after it is downloaded append it to the page. <html src="https:// ... /file.html"> is not valid. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057801/how-can-i-use-fetch-api-to-populate-a-div for how to place html in a div ... but the file.html you have has a body onload event -- that is not going to happen.